# Problemas para executar áudios em aplicações javascript com nw.js

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando com uma aplicação javascript que precisa ser executada offline em um ambiente desktop. Utilizei o [Node Webkit](http://nwjs.io/) para empacotar minha aplicação e gerar um arquivo executável.  Porém, após criar esse pacote, os áudios pararam de tocar. Através do app.exe consigo analisar o console e verificar se  está ocorrendo algum erro, mas nada acontece.

Vocês conhecem alguma solução para transformar um projeto web javascript para rodar via desktop funcionando os audios corretamente?

Comment: Seus áudios estão em que formato? Se não me engano, o NW não suporta alguns formatos de áudio (e acho que MP3 seria um deles), por uma questão de licença.

Comment: Olá, bfavaretto! Então, estou utilizando *.ogg e *.mp3. Nenhum deles é carregado.

Comment: Veja https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-MP3-%26-MP4-(H.264)-using-the--video--%26--audio--tags. e https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1208

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou analisar essa informação. Qualquer coisa eu tento utilizar outro builder. :)